Azure Functions App makes a lot of transactions to Blob Storage
I have Durable Functions in Azure Functions App and recently noticed that the Functions App is making a lot of transactions to the Blob Storage attached to the Functions App.
The app makes roughly 37,600 transactions per hour. The transaction types with the most transactions are GetQueueMetadata and PeekMessages. Also, GetBlobProperties, GetBlob, and QueryTables transaction types have a lot of transactions, roughly 7,500 per hour.
The Function App is currently not in use, it's just sitting idle with no invocations.
The transaction count was significantly lower roughly two months ago and suddenly increased 22x even though I didn't push new code or make any changes to the Functions, Function App configurations, or storage configurations.
The Function App is on the Consumption plan. The function runtime version is "~4", stack is Python and Python version is 3.10. There are 14 activities, 7 HTTP triggers, and 8 orchestrators.
There is a discussion about this on this GitHub Issue from 2018 and the issue was fixed.
Things that I've tried:
Stopping the Function App stopped the transactions.
Pushing the same code to another Function App didn't result in more transactions for that new Function App.
Edit: checked again later and got the same behavior also in the new Function App so the issue seems to be in the code.
Host.json for the problematic Function App:
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}

Host.json for the new Function App is identical.
What could be the issue?
Is there some further information that I should provide or debugging steps that I could take?
Edit:
Code to replicate the behavior:
import azure.functions as func
import azure.durable_functions as durable_functions

polling_cost_test_blueprint = durable_functions.Blueprint()

@polling_cost_test_blueprint.route(route="polling_cost_test")
@polling_cost_test_blueprint.durable_client_input(client_name="client")
async def polling_cost_test_route_1(req: func.HttpRequest, client):
    payload = req.get_json()
    instance_id = await client.start_new(
        "polling_cost_test_orchestrator", None, payload
    )
    response = client.create_check_status_response(req, instance_id)
    return response

# Repeat the same function but with a different name 10 times

@polling_cost_test_blueprint.orchestration_trigger(context_name="context")
def polling_cost_test_orchestrator(context):
    payload = context.get_input()
    try:
        yield context.call_activity_with_retry(
            "polling_cost_test_activity",
            None,
            payload,
        )
        return "Test completed"
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

# Repeat the same function but with a different name 10 times

@polling_cost_test_blueprint.activity_trigger(input_name="payload")
async def polling_cost_test_activity(payload):
    return None

# Repeat the same function but with a different name 10 times

I also experimented with this by the number of triggers, orchestrators, and activities, and the transactions increased/decreased as a result.
At this point, I'll just assume that this is normal functioning for Azure Durable Functions and the behavior can be controlled by setting the maxQueuePollingInterval + having fewer triggers, orchestrators & activities.
However, I'm still baffled as to why the transaction count suddenly increased 22x even though I didn't edit the code.

You could try increasing the maxQueuePollingInterval in host.json: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2C2x-durable-functions&pivots=programming-language-csharp#host-json. The Function app checks for new messages in the Storage queues by polling so that is probably where those requests come from.

@Toivo Mattila - Is your issue resolved ?

"Pushing the same code to another Function App didn't result in more transactions for that new Function App". This is pretty interesting. So you're saying it's not related to the Function invocations themselves, because they don't behave that way when added to a new Project?

@juunas Thanks! I'll try this on Monday! Also, thank you for your article "How Azure Durable Functions scale". It helped me better understand how Azure Functions work.

@Harshitha I'll try the suggested solution on Monday and get back to you.

@juunas I set the maxQueuePollingInterval to 6 hours. It has been running for a while, had no incoming requests, and should have reached the maximum polling interval, but changing the max polling interval had no effect. Is there some way to confirm that the configuration is correct?

@AndrewB I rechecked this today and now the new function also has the same situation. This suggests that the problem is in the code. I'll try adding more functions to see if that increases the transaction count.

Yes that sounds about right. Perhaps you could share a sanitised version of your code? Of particular importance is to show what you're doing with any loops or while clauses etc. I wonder if you're accidentally causing a lot of activity in the underlying Replay log, which is backed by the Azure Storage account. We'll know more if we can see the code.

@AndrewB I'll see what I can do for the sanitized code. In the meantime, would this still be an issue even if the Functions were never triggered & functions just always sitting idle?

@AndrewB Added the code for reproducing the issue to the question + some more information. At this point, I'll assume this is a "it's a feature, not a bug"-scenario, though I wouldn't mind being wrong.

Unfortunately I'm a C# dev rather than a Python dev; but what I find unusual is the yield context.call_activity_with_retry( . What's the reason for using yield? My understanding is that it's for a generator, normally within a loop. But I can't see a loop. What's this meant to be doing?

The yield seems to be just the Azure Durable Functions syntax in Python according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/quickstart-python-vscode?tabs=windows%2Cazure-cli-set-indexing-flag&pivots=python-mode-decorators#enable-the-v2-programming-model
Honestly, I don't understand why it is used in this context either. To me it seems like a weird design decision from MS. And yes, you are correct, yield is typically used with generators and in a loop of some kind.

Out of interest if you replace your yield with just a simple await does that change the behaviour?

Then the Function fails to start and throws Exception: SyntaxError: 'await' outside async function
